# How do I define a conditional attribute selector in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to set all items of specific class to a specific value, but IF it has a specific attribute set, it must match a condition.

Example:

```
<div class="address"></div>
<div class="address" data-address-type="from"></div>
<div class="address" data-address-type="to"></div>
```

I want to set all address to "123 Some Address Road". However, if there is a data-address-type, only if the data-address-type is "to".

```
$('.address[data-address-type="to"]').text('123 Some Address Road');
```

The above will not change the elements where data-address-type is not defined.

Comment: There are no conditional selectors. Use the `.filter()` method.

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nSW7L/1/

Comment: You need quotes around the 'to' - they have to be different than the apostrophe you use around the whole selector. Change it to "to" and try that.

Comment: Ty @trojansdestroy - That was a typo though... fixed!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use a `filter()` for this, in `.address` elements filter elements which either does not have the `data-address-type` attribute using `:not([data-address-type])` or `data-address-type` has the value `to` using `[data-address-type="to"]`

```
$('.address').filter(':not([data-address-type]), [data-address-type="to"]').html('')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nSW7L/)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you... Stackoverflow wants me to wait a couple minutes before accepting, but this is it. Much thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

`[data-address-type='to']` means `attribute` data-address-type having `value` equal to to.

```
$(".address[data-address-type='to'],.address:not([data-address-type])").text("123 Some Address Road");
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/T6MGe/)

[More information here.](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: This would not change the address where data-address-type is not defined.

Comment: @Bradley you are defining "`$('.address[data-address-type='to']').text('123 Some Address Road');` The above will not change the elements where data-address-type is not defined." after I post answer and now down voting??? why??? be clear about your question first and have courtesy to inform about your edits rather than straight away down voting

Comment: I think this statement in the original question was very clear: "However, if there is a data-address-type, only if the data-address-type is 'to'." And I wasn't going to comment on my downvote, but I don't have a choice now because I don't want the OP to be implicated for something that wasn't his fault.

Comment: I didn't downvote anything. @BoltClock, Thanks - I thought it was clear too.

Comment: sorry I thought you did

Comment: Hiral, you should edit this post to correct it. This basically just re-iterates what the asker already knows works for the 'to' cases but fails to address the cases where there is no 'data-address-type' attribute. Remember, once you edit, your post is bumped to the top of the active page so the community will see it and can vote on it. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of `$(".address")` and the [Attribute Equals Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) or [Attribute Not Equal Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/).

Comment: `[data-address-type!='to']` is essentially the same as `:not([data-address-type='to'])` which matches elements without the attribute.